# How to create slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, slider

I want to create slider in percentage ..here is the image of the slider

[image: slider->]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`syncfusion_flutter_sliders`](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders) package.

```dart
SfSlider.vertical(value: value, onChanged: onChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this package: [syncfusion_flutter_sliders](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders)

```
double _value = 40.0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter Vertical Slider'),
    ),
    body: SfSlider.vertical(
      min: 0.0,
      max: 100.0,
      value: _value,
      interval: 20,
      showTicks: true,
      showLabels: true,
      enableTooltip: true,
      minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
      onChanged: (dynamic value) {
        setState(() {
          _value = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: after using this sfslider this throwing me a error

Comment: Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: please add your full code and the line you got the error.

Comment: It is not a free package to use... please refer to its license.